# Click UI element in window not working on Power Automate Desktop

Tags: ui-automation, power-automate, microsoft-ui-automation, power-automate-desktop

I am building a flow where I need to use UI clicks using Power Automate Desktop. I want to perform UI clicks on a window where there is a menu items[Basic, Payment, Details].

On starting flow I will perform UI clicks in 'Basic' section, later I want to switch to 'Payment' section, Now UI click is not working to switch to 'Payment'section.

I tried 'Get details of the UI element in window' to check about the UI element. I getting the false from 'Get details of the UI element in window'. Its like it doesn't enabled, How can I enable it? How to perform UI click on a menu section?
UI click worked every where in the window except on the menu section.

Below is the image of the flow, you might get clarity on what I am saying.

[image: Check the flow here!]

Comment: Is it a programming question? Is it a question about Power Automate or about UI automation?

Comment: It is a question about Power Automate Desktop UI automation, it doesn't working at specific ui element.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved, I tried 'send mouse click' action and it was worked exactly the way I want.